# Spring Cloud Stream Security

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Looking to use Spring Cloud Stream on a new project for an event driven approach, however I can't seem to find any docs on security. We are using OAuth2 for our rest security, does anyone have any advice for Stream?

Comment: Adding to this question, basically is how do we add JWT to the messages in Streams. And is there a way to validate those tokens on consumption? Imagine that if you have a REST endpoint and a stream that consume the same payload, you want security to be applied in an uniform way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Cloud Stream in your application, you can add any `security` related capabilities like any typical Spring Boot or Spring application to your app itself. Do you specifically see anything missing in Spring Cloud Stream from the `security` aspect. Please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: So what I want to do is guarantee that events published to do bus have originated from trusted sources, I was wondering whether the payload can be signed? I know I can code this myself just wondering if it's supported out of the box